# Yet another probability question.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> A nuclear reactor is equipped with 2 safety systems. The first safety
>   system will work in 90% of the cases. If it doesn't work, the second safety system will start to work, but it only works in 80% of the cases. What is the probability that no safety
>   system will alarm the employers of the nuclear reactor?

***My attempt*:**

Let $S$ denote that an alarm works and $F$ that no alarm works. Write $(F,S)$ for the outcome "The first alarm doesn't work, the second does" and analoguous for the others.

Then, $\mathbb{P}(\{F,F\}) = \mathbb{P}(\{(F,F),(S,F)\} \cap\{(F,F),(F,S)\}) $

$= \mathbb{P}(\{(F,F),(S,F)\} \mid\{(F,F),(F,S)\})\mathbb{P}(\{(F,F),(F,S)\}) = (0.2)(0.1) = 1/50$

Is this correct?

It seems tedious to write this always out this way. Can I avoid this?

Comment: "Assuming the events are independent, the probability that both alarms fail is $.2\cdot .1 = 1/50.$"

Comment: P(system 1 off and system 2 off) = P(2 off | 1 off) P(1 off), this means .2*.1 = .02. They give you the conditional probability: " the second safety system will start to work, but it only works in 80% of the cases."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can avoid it.

Let $F_1$ denote the event that the first alarmsystem will fail and let $F_2$ denote the event that the second alarmsystem will fail.

Then: $$\mathsf P(F_1\cap F_2)=P(F_1)P(F_2\mid F_1)=P(F_1)P(F_2)=0.1\cdot0.2=0.02$$here the second equality is based on independence.

Note that this can apparantly be solved without any bothering what the underlying probability space looks like.

Here you find a [nice question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2233731/75923) about that subject.

It is important that you know about underlying probability spaces but there comes a time (if you persevere in probability theory) that you will hardly ever bother about them anymore.