# $\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{(H,T)\}}\mid \mathcal F]$ here?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

We consider the experience : toss two fair coin simultaneously. 
Let $$\mathcal F=\sigma\Big(\big\{(H,T),(T,H)\big\},\{(H,H)\},\{(T,T)\}\Big),$$
and $$\mathbb P\{(H,H)\}=\mathbb P\{(T,T)\}=1/4\quad \text{and}\quad \mathbb P\{(H,T),(T,H)\}=1/2.$$

What is $$\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{(T,H)\}}\mid \mathcal F]\ \ ?$$

I know that it's the best approximation of $\boldsymbol 1_{\{(H,T)\}}$ knowing $\mathcal F$, but I really don't know how to compute it.

I know that $$\mathbb E[X\mid Y=y_i]=\frac{1}{\mathbb P\{Y=y_i\}}\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_{Y=y_1}],$$
or $$\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=\sum_{y}\frac{1}{\mathbb P\{Y=y\}}\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_{\{Y=y\}}]$$
but I can't use this formula here, do I ?

Comment: The indicator function inside the expectation is measurable with respect to the algebra F. Hence, the conditional expectation of the indicator given the algebra is just the indicator function.

Comment: Sorry I misread the algebra. The correct answer should be:
$\frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol 1_{\{(T,H),(T,H) \} }$
This is because the only thing you know is that the outcomes of the coin tosses were different, and not the same. Given that, the probability that the first toss was T (which is all is left to know), is 1/2.

Comment: The question only makes sense if the outcomes of the two coins are distinguishable. If that is not the case then $(H,T)$ is not an outcome of your sample space and consequently $\mathbf1_{\{(H,T)\}}$ is not measurable. The fact that you use the term "simultaneously" makes me suspect that the outcomes are not distinguishable. What space do you use as outcome space?

Comment: @drhab: I know that $\boldsymbol 1_{\{(H,T)\}}$ is not measurable wrt $\mathcal F$. If we consider $\mathcal G$, then $\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{(T,H)\}}\mid \mathcal G]=\boldsymbol 1_{\{(H,T)\}}$ and is not interesting. The question makes really sense in this context since $\boldsymbol 1_{\{(H,T)\}}$ is not $\mathcal F-$measurable but $\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{(H,T)\}}\mid \mathcal F]$ is $\mathcal F-$measurable. The space I use is the one written in the question : $\mathcal F=\sigma (\{(H,H)\},\{T,T\},{\color{red}\{ }(H,T),(T,H){\color{red}\}})$

Comment: I am not concerned about measurability wrt $\mathcal F$ but wrt $\mathcal G$ where $(\Omega,\mathcal G,P)$ is the underlying probability space. My question is: is $(H,T)$ an element of $\Omega$? The use of the word "simultaneously" indicates it is not or at least not necessarily, because then you can do it with $\Omega=\{(H,H),(T,T),\{(H,T),(T,H)\}\}$ that does not contain $(H,T)$. If $\{(H,T)\}\notin\mathcal G$ then $1_{(H,T)}$ is not a measurable function and $\mathbb E[1_{(H,T)}\mid\mathcal F]$ is not defined.

Comment: $\Omega =\{(H,T),(T,H),(H,H),(T,T)\}$ with event space $\sigma (\{(H,H)\},\{(T,T)\},\{(H,T),(T,H)\})$, $\mathbb P\{(H,H)\}=\mathbb P\{(T,T)\}=1/4$ and $\mathbb P\{(H,T),(T,H)\}=1/4$. I.e. $\{(H,T)\}$ and $\{(T,H)\}$ is not measurable. @drhab

Comment: If $(\Omega,\mathcal G,P)$ is the probability space and $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal G$ is a sub-sigma-algebra then $\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal F]$ only makes sense for $\mathcal G$-measurable $X$. Your $X$ is not $\mathcal G$-measurable.

Comment: @drhab : Take $\mathcal G=2^\Omega $, then it make sense (because $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ can be prolonge in $(\Omega ,2^\Omega , \mathbb P)$ (as you said in a previous space, all discret probability spsace can be taken in the power set). No ?

Comment: That is correct, but in accordance take away the word "simultaneously". The coins must be distinguishable. E.g. a first and a second toss. How else can $(H,T)$ be discerned from $(T,H)$?

Comment: But If $\Omega =\{(H,H),(H,T),(T,H),(T,T)\}$ with $\mathcal F$ as I wrote in my original post doesn't it mean that the coin are not distinguishable ? (as I said). And thus, indeed, $\{(H,T)\}$ and $\{(T,H)\}$ doesn't occur (since it's not in the event space).  And after we prolonge to all $2^\Omega $... no ? @drhab

Comment: @drhab: By the way, with this experiment (i.e. coin are not distinguishable), how would you take $2^\Omega $ as event space ? Because what I did is really take $\mathcal F=\sigma (\{(H,H)\},\{(T,T)\},\{(T,H),(H,T)\})$ and then prolonge it on $2^\Omega $. But how can you write this experiment directly on $2^\Omega $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two fair coins are thrown and $X$ denotes the number of heads thrown in total.

In this answer I use probability space $(\Omega,\wp(\Omega),P)$ where $\Omega=\{(H,H),(H,T),(T,H),(T,T)\}$ and $P(\{\omega\})=\frac14$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

Further $\mathcal F$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\{(H,H)\},\{(T,T)\},\{(H,T),(T,H)\}\}\subseteq\wp(\Omega)$

Then your question can be interpreted as: $$\text{"what is }\mathbb E[\mathbf1_{\{(T,H)\}}\mid X]\text{?"}$$

This because: $\sigma(X)=\mathcal F$.

We find:

- $\mathbb E[\mathbf1_{\{(T,H)\}}\mid X=0]=0$
- $\mathbb E[\mathbf1_{\{(T,H)\}}\mid X=1]=P(\{(H,T)\}\mid X=1)=\frac12$
- $\mathbb E[\mathbf1_{\{(T,H)\}}\mid X=2]=0$

This allows the conclusion:$$\mathbb E[\mathbf1_{\{(T,H)\}}\mid X]=\frac12\mathbf1_{\{X=1\}}=\frac12\mathbf1_{\{(H,T),(T,H)\}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really don't get something : **1)** We toss two not distinguishable coins. The probability space is $\Omega =\{(H,H),(T,H),(T,T),(H,T)\}$ s.t. $\mathcal F=\sigma (\{(H,H)\},\{(T,T)\},\{(H,T),(T,H)\})$ and $$\mathbb P\{(H,H)\}=\mathbb P\{(T,T)\}=\frac{1}{4}\quad \text{and}\quad \mathbb P\{(T,H),(H,T)\}=\frac{1}{2}.$$ That is correct ? (it's written in the solution of my exercise, so it must be correct I guess :)).

Comment: **2)** Now we can prolonge this space on $(\Omega ,2^\Omega ,\mathbb Q)$ where $\mathbb Q(A)=\mathbb P(A)$ if $A\in \mathcal F$ and $$\mathbb Q\{(T,H)\}=\mathbb Q\{(H,T)\}=\frac{1}{4}.$$

This make sense right ? And now, the question is what is $$\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{(H,T)\}}\mid \mathcal F].$$ And it's written that even if $\boldsymbol 1_{\{(H,T)\}}$ is not $\mathcal F-$measurable, the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{(H,T)\}}\mid \mathcal F]$ is $\mathcal F-$measurable.

Comment: **3)** At the end, of the solution, my teacher wrote : we could have consider the space $\tilde\Omega =\{\{H,H\},\{H,T\},\{T,T\}\}$ with $\mathcal G=2^\Omega $ and $\mathbf P$ s.t. $\mathbf P\{H,H\}=\mathbf P\{T,T\}=1/4$ and $\mathbf P\{T,H\}=1/2$, but we can't prolonge such a space to give $\boldsymbol 1_{\{(H,T)\}}$ measurable, whereas is the previous me can.

Comment: Could you please tel me what do you think about my three previous point ? Many thanks for your time and your answers :) (I'm sure I'm near to understand).

Comment: 1) If we toss two non-distinguishable coins then we can use $\mathcal F$ as $\sigma$-algebra in stead of $\wp(\Omega)$. But doing so that means that event $\{(T,H)\}$ is not a recognizable event. Then (conditional) expectation of its indicator function is not defined. That was my objection against your setup.

Comment: 2) I am not familiar with the term prolonge, but if we want to go for $\mathbf E1_{\{(T,H)\}}$ (conditional or not) then we must go for a probability space that contains $\{(T,H)\}$ as an event, and we can take $\wp(\Omega)$ instead of $\mathcal F$. This happens in my answer and a $\mathcal F$-measurable expression is found there for $\mathbb E[\mathbf1_{\{(T,H)\}}\mid\mathcal F]$ while $\mathbf1_{\{(T,H)\}}$ itself is not $\mathcal F$-measurable.

Comment: 3) I suspect that concerns the fact that $\{H,T\}$ cannot be split up in two sets of which one represents $(H,T)$ and the other $(T,H)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and your time. Very helpful :-) In your answer, when you consider $(\Omega ,\mathcal P(\Omega ),\mathbb P)$ with $\mathbb P\{\omega \}$, it doesn't represent the experiment "tossing two not distinguishable coins", does it ?

Comment: The outcome space in my answer corresponds with tossing distinguishable coins. One last thing: do not bother too much about the looks of underlying probability spaces. I assure you that once upon a time you will not be occupied by that anymore. For instance have a look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2233731/169789) and its answer(s).

Comment: Thank you very much :) (I just want to understand in the very simple case :)) Can we say that you first consider the distinguishable case $(\Omega ,\mathcal P(\Omega ),\mathbb P)$, and they adapt to the undistinguishable case by introducing $\mathcal F=\sigma (\{(H,H),(T,T), \{(H,T),(T,H)\}\})$ ? It can make sense ? I will read with attention your link. Thank you for that :)

Comment: Yes you can say that. It does not harm to induce an order in the tossing. It might be that events come up that are not relevant but again: that does not harm. If you want to focus on a coarser situation then that is possible. If in a coarse probability space you want to focus on finer then that is *not* possible.

Comment: "If in a coarse probability space you want to focus on finer then that is not possible." Then I get it. I agree that "prolongement" is strange since we can do it in many different way. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your study on probability theory.

Comment: Well done, good and faithful servant ! xD