# Definition of conditional probability and a problem.

Tags: probability

**The Problem:**

An urn contains 3 red and 4 black balls and another contains 4 red and 5 black.

A random ball is chosen from the first urn and is inserted into the second urn.

After this a random ball is chosen from the second urn.

Consider the events:
$A$ : "first ball is red", $B$ : "second ball is red".

Find the Probability $P_A(B)$ where "$P_A(B)$" means the probability that $B$ happens if $A$ has happened (i.e. the conditional probability of $B$ given $A$).

This is a simple problem right?

**Why I'm confused:**

But I'm confused. We work in the probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$
(in this case $\Sigma=\mathcal P(\Omega)$), and $P$ is a probability that means is a function which respect kolmogorov axioms.

$P_A(B)=1/2$ (because if $A$ happened then in the second urn we will have 5 red balls and 5 black balls)

**My question:**

Here is my question: If $P_A(B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$ by definition (and $P $ is a function, we don't know what function just this function respect Kolmogorov axioms). How we came to the conclusion $P_A(B)=1/2$? Using
$$\frac{\text{Number of Favorable Outcomes}}{\text{Total Number of Possible Outcomes}}?$$
This doesn't make sense for me. $P$ is fixed from the beginning, then we must find $P_A(B)$ using definition to be rigorous. I need a rigourous proof.

Comment: "Using $\dfrac{\text{Number of Favorable Outcomes}}{\text{Total Number of Possible Outcomes}}$"... Be very careful with that as it is frequently incorrect.  You may only say a probability is for sure the number of favorable divided by total number of outcomes in the event that each outcome is equally likely to occur.  In many problems that is not going to be the case.  There are two outcomes to a lottery, you either win or you lose, but you certainly don't win with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Your questions are legal and characteristic for someone who emphatically is taught that probability theory on this level is utterly depending on probability spaces. Let me try to put at ease: I predict that - if you gain more and more insight in probability theory - once upon a time questions like this will not bother you anymore. Also I like to refer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2233731/169789) and its answers on the subject. By solving problems we usually do not have to wonder how the underlying probability space (more than one possibilities) looks like.

Comment: Note that you will _practically never_ be able to deduce a probability distribution by rigorous application of the axioms to a problem that is posed in terms like these, because even if you can make a list of outcomes that happen to be equally likely, there is no basis in the probability axioms for saying the likelihood is equal. Instead, when the problem does not explicitly state a probability distribution, you must make a judgment about what probability distribution the problem-setter _meant_ it to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you raised is a legitimate one. The calculation leading to $\frac12$ in your question (and the calculations in both of the answers available as I write this) use the assumption that, when a ball is drawn from an urn, each of the balls in that urn is equally likely to be drawn. That assumption is part of what people usually understand by the phrase "a random ball is chosen", which occurs twice in the problem.  Sometimes people express this more explicitly by saying that a ball is chosen "uniformly at random".

It is certainly possible to have physical situations where this assumption is incorrect. For example, if all the red balls are much smaller than the blue ones, settle to the bottom of the urn, and are almost impossible to find and grab. Then pulling a "random" ball from such an urn would not make all the balls equally probable.

The general theory of probability, with its arbitrary probability function $P$, is designed to apply to all situations, even ones where the sizes of the balls or some other irregularities make some balls more likely to be chosen than others. To solve problems like the one you quoted, one needs additional information about the function $P$. In the case at hand, "a random ball is chosen" was intended to supply the additional information that all balls in an urn are equally likely to be chosen.

Answer (score 7):

> (And $P$ is a function, we don't know what function just this function respect Kolmogorov axioms)

We do know more.   We know that our $\mathsf P$ is the probability measure for the events of *the described process*.   It has to obey the Kolmogrov axioms, but *also* be evaluated according to *reasoning* about the selection proceedure.

Here too our $\Omega$ is not just an abstraction, but a set of outcomes for this ball selection process. Likewise our $\mathcal F$ is the event algebra for this *particular* probability space, and our events, $A$ and $B$, are contained with in it.

$\mathsf P_A(B)$, which is more commonly written $\mathsf P(B\mid A)$, is the probability for selecting one from the red balls in the second urn *when given* that one red ball was added to the four red, and five black, balls originally in that urn.   This is just the probability for obtaining one from *five* red balls among *ten* balls. Hence $\mathsf P_A(B)$ equals $\tfrac 5{10}$.

$\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ is the probability for selecting one from the *three* red balls among the *seven* balls in the first urn to place in the second urn, then selecting one from the *four-plus-one* red balls among the *nine-plus-one* balls in the second urn.   So $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ equals $\tfrac 37\cdot\tfrac 5{10}$, which is $\tfrac {15}{70}$.

$\mathsf P(A)$ is the probability of selecting one from the *three* red balls among the *seven* balls in the first urn, which is just $\tfrac 37$.   So clearly $\mathsf P(A\cap B)/\mathsf P(A)$ does equal $\tfrac 5{10}$ as anticipated.

Answer (score 4):

$P(A)=\frac37$.  What is $P(A\cap B)$?  First we draw a red ball from urn $1$ with probability $\frac37$.  Then we independently draw a red ball from urn $2$ with probability ${5\over10}$.  So $$P(A\cap B)=\frac37\cdot{5\over10}={3\over14}$$ and $$P_A(B)={3/7\over3/14}=\frac12.$$

Initially, we have $70$ outcomes: $7$ ways to draw a ball from urn $1$ and $10$ ways to draw a ball from urn $2$.  Once we say that a red ball is drawn from urn $1$ we discard $40$ of those outcomes, and there are only $30$ left.  I think you may be a bit confused when you say, "$P$ is fixed from the beginning."  This is true of course, but $P_A$ is not the sam as $P$.  Once we condition on $A$ we have a different probability space.  The events are different, since those where a black ball is drawn first are gone.  Of the $30$ remaining events $15$ are favorable: draw one of the $3$ red balls from urn $1$ and then draw one of the $5$ red balls from urn $2$.

Comment: Why $P(A)=3/7$ Of course i know ...but remember $P$ is a function which respect Kolmogorov axioms. This is all I know. From here maybe we can define $P(A)=3/7$ (because is intuitive and more define $P(E) $where $E$ is an event, and check if $P$ is a probability on $\Omega$) but I'm not sure.

Comment: @IcaSandu I don't understand what you mean.  $P$ is a probability measure, yes.  That statement alone is not sufficient to determine any of the values of $P$ except $P(\emptyset)=0,\ P(A)=1.$