# Formalising some very basic probabilistic problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Often, I encounter some problem were probability is involved. On an intuitive level, I understand I think what is going on but when I have to formalize it with probability spaces I am a bit lost.

For example :

"Pick an edge uniformly at random in a graph". I understand what this mean. It means that I pick any edge of the graph with probability $1/m$ where $m$ is the number of edges in the graph. But what is the probability space here? We have $\Omega = \{edges\}$ right? Is there a uniform random variable involved $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$? I know that I should have $P(X=e_i)=\frac{1}{\mid \text{\{edges\}} \mid}$ but then it seems like the random variable goes from $\Omega$ to $\Omega$ which is kind of weird. What is this random variable actually?

Comment: "*Is there a uniform random variable involved*"?  If you want to be incredibly pedantic.  Random variables are a very specific type of object that we investigate in probability who are functions with codomain some measurable space, giving us a way to measure a particular event from our sample space with respect to this possibly different measure.  If you are talking about real-valued random variables specifically, that measurable space for the codomain has to specifically be the real numbers.  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition).

Comment: You might as well say, "No, random variables aren't involved here (*yet*)" as an answer to your question.  If you were to continue your question with "*Pick an edge uniformly at random in a graph.  What is the probability that the edge is incident to (i.e. shares a vertex with) at least 4 other edges*" then we could talk about the random variable $X$ which counts the number of edges a particular edge is incident to.  Otherwise, your function $P(X=e_i)=\frac{1}{|\{\text{edges}\}|}$ is just the probability measure, not a random variable.

Comment: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. You want your random variable to take values in the set of edges, which I denote by $E$. So what you want is $X\colon \Omega \to E$ with $\mathbb{P}(X = e) = \frac{1}{|E|}$ for every $e \in E$. You don't have to specify what $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is, what's important is that it exists.

Comment: If you want a concrete way of constructing $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, you can take $\Omega = E$, $\mathbb{P}$ the uniform probability measure on $E$ (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\lbrace e\rbrace ) = \frac{1}{|E|}$ for every $e \in E$) and $X \colon E \to E$ the identity map.

Comment: It might be that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2233731/169789) and its answer(s) is interesting for you. There you find why it is not really needed to specify a probability space. As @Michh says: what's important is that it exists.